# Которые или которых

Tags: языкознание

У нас в городе висят щиты с рекламой о продаже квартир. И там написано: "КВАРТИРЫ, КОТОРЫХ ЖДАЛИ". По-моему "которых" возможно применять только по отношению к одушевленным предметам. Но если мы напишем: "Квартиры, которые ждали", то получится, что квартиры чего-то ждали  ).
Получается, что фраза построена неверно?

Answer (score 6):

Вы в своем вопросе практически и ответили. Действительно, "квартиры, которых ждали"- ошибка. "Которые ждали" - двусмысленно. Почему бы не добавить слово мы? "Квартиры, которые мы ждали". Как отмечают многие преподаватели-лингвисты, почти в каждом рекламном слогане - ошибка. Ведь он должен быть кратким, образным,привлекающим внимание. За всем этим правильность часто отходит на второй план. А потом  реклама начинает влиять на речь. И уже никого не удивляет ни то, что один сок сочнее другого, ни выражения "до трех раз больше" и т.п.

Answer (score 4):

Ошибки нет.
Глагол "ждать" допускает при себе как винительный (которые [мы] ждали...), так и родительный (которых [мы] ждали...) падеж.  
Сравните: ждать поезда - ждать поезд. Об варианта возможны, хотя смысл несколько разный. 
Ощущение ошибки возникает, видимо, в силу непривычности использования "ждать" в сочетании с дополнением "которых" и интуитивного желания согласовать падеж с определяемым словом основного предложения.

Comment: Согласна, о вариативности управления я как-то не подумала.Но слоган лучше бы смотрелся с вин. падежом из-за двойного смысла.

Comment: Не уверен. Если ориентироваться на то, что родительный отвечает за абстрактный объект (ждать трамвая), а винительный - за абстрактный (ждать трамвай в котором я вчера ехал), то скорее именно "которых". Хотя это надо смотреть по смыслу. Если каких-то новых, навороченных - то да, "которые". Если просто о долгожданном жилье - то "которых".

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка налицо. А вот если бы было написано по правилам, слоган даже выиграл бы, ведь профессиональные слоганы должны быть образны, метафоричны, некоторая двусмысленность им не мешает:"Квартиры, которые ждали (мы)", "Квартиры, которые ждали (нас)" - всё нормально.

Comment: Например: Слоган 1: «Инструмент, заточенный на лидерство» отображает и  его положительные качества (заточенный = острый, точный); и в то же время используется сленговое (=направленный <на>), что намекает на открытость компании и ее близость к рядовому покупателю. Слоган 2: «Виртуозный осевой инструмент»- используется игра слов,«инструмент»  может быть не только рабочим, но и музыкальным. Эпитет «виртуозный» позволяет тонко намекнуть на высокое качество товара и обозначить целевую аудиторию, выразив свое восхищение ее мастерством